# When joining two tables with SQL, I get null values for two of my columns in the results

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join

These are the tables I created

```
CREATE TABLE PROJECT 
(
    ProjectID   Int          NOT NULL IDENTITY (1000, 100),
    ProjectName Char(50)     NOT NULL,
    Department  Char(35)     NOT NULL,
    MaxHours    Numeric(8,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 100,
    StartDate   DateTime     NULL,
    EndDate     DateTime     NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PROJECT_PK PRIMARY KEY (ProjectID),
    CONSTRAINT PROJ_DEPART_FK FOREIGN KEY(Department)
                              REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(DepartmentName)
                                  ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE ASSIGNMENT 
(
    ProjectID      Int      NOT NULL,
    EmployeeNumber Int      NOT NULL,
    HoursWorked    Numeric(6,2) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT ASSIGNMENT_PK PRIMARY KEY (ProjectID, EmployeeNumber),
    CONSTRAINT ASSIGN_PROJ_FK FOREIGN KEY (ProjectID)
                              REFERENCES PROJECT (ProjectID)
                                  ON UPDATE NO ACTION
                                  ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT ASSIGN_EMP_FK FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeNumber)
                             REFERENCES EMPLOYEE (EmployeeNumber)
                                  ON UPDATE NO ACTION
                                  ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
```

This is the query I am running

```
SELECT 
    A.ProjectID, E.FirstName, E.LastName, A.HoursWorked
FROM
    ASSIGNMENT A
LEFT JOIN 
    EMPLOYEE E ON A.ProjectID = E.EmployeeNumber
```

This is the result I got

```
ProjectID   FirstName   LastName    HoursWorked
------------------------------------------------
1000        NULL        NULL        30.00
1000        NULL        NULL        65.00
1000        NULL        NULL        55.00
1100        NULL        NULL        40.00
1100        NULL        NULL        45.00
1200        NULL        NULL        25.00
1200        NULL        NULL        20.00
1200        NULL        NULL        45.00
1200        NULL        NULL        40.00
1300        NULL        NULL        35.00
1300        NULL        NULL        50.00
1400        NULL        NULL        15.00
1400        NULL        NULL        10.00
1400        NULL        NULL        27.50
```

The data that was inserted

```
/*****   PROJECT DATA   *********************************************************/

INSERT INTO PROJECT VALUES(
    '2010 Q3 Product Plan', 'Marketing', 135.00, '10-MAY-10', '15-JUN-10');
INSERT INTO PROJECT VALUES(
    '2010 Q3 Portfolio Analysis', 'Finance', 120.00, '05-JUL-10', '05-JUL-10' );
INSERT INTO PROJECT VALUES(
    '2010 Q3 Tax Preparation', 'Accounting', 145.00, '10-AUG-10', '15-OCT-10');
INSERT INTO PROJECT VALUES(
    '2010 Q4 Product Plan', 'Marketing', 150.00, '10-AUG-10', '15-SEP-10');
INSERT INTO PROJECT (ProjectName, Department, MaxHours, StartDate)              
    VALUES(                                     
    '2010 Q4 Portfolio Analysis', 'Finance', 140.00, '05-OCT-10');          

/*****   ASSIGNMENT DATA   ******************************************************/

INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES(1000, 1, 30.0);
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES(1000, 8, 75.0);
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES(1000, 10, 55.0);
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES(1100, 4, 40.0);
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES(1100, 6, 45.0);
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES(1200, 1, 25.0);
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES(1200, 2, 20.0);
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES(1200, 4, 45.0);
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES(1200, 5, 40.0);
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES(1300, 1, 35.0);
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES(1300, 8, 80.0);
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES(1300, 10, 50.0);
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES(1400, 4, 15.0);
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES(1400, 5, 10.0);
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES(1400, 6, 27.5);
```

When I run a query for just the first and last name columns, all the names show up and are definitely not null. I am very inexperienced with JOIN statements so im not sure if this is correct. I tried using "RiGHT JOIN" but this made the other two columns NULL, instead of the firstname and last name columns. How can i make the results display without any NULL values at all?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?It seem that can equal those table by `ON A.ProjectID = E.EmployeeNumber`

Comment: I want the FirstName and lastName columns to not be null. I inserted data in those columns. So i expects them to not be NULL. Im not sure what you aking me to provide

Comment: I mean you could show us some data from `PROJECT` and `ASSIGNMENT` tables. that really help

Comment: Okay i updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are joining on project id and employee number.  That doesn't make sense.

A sensible query would be:

```
SELECT A.ProjectID, P.ProjectName, P.Department, A.HoursWorked
FROM  ASSIGNMENT A
      PROJECT P
      ON A.ProjectID = P.ProjectId;
```

If you want information about employees, then you need an `EMPLOYEE` table.  Then something like this would work:

```
SELECT A.ProjectID, E.FirstName, E.LastName, A.HoursWorked
FROM ASSIGNMENT A LEFT JOIN
     EMPLOYEE E 
     ON A.EmployeeNumber = E.EmployeeNumber
```